# JSDOC: How to override/redefine type of a property from an existing type?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

In Meteor there is a type:

```
    interface User {
        _id: string;
        username?: string | undefined;
        emails?: UserEmail[] | undefined;
        createdAt?: Date | undefined;
        profile?: any;
        services?: any;
    }
```

Then how do I make the IntelliSense to recognize `User.profile` as my type `MyProfile`?

Comment: Why don't you define the profile as `profile?: MyProfile` instead of `profile?: any`?

Comment: It's Meteor's code, not mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the `User` interface and override the profile type.

```
interface User {
  _id: string;
  username?: string | undefined;
  emails?: UserEmail[] | undefined;
  createdAt?: Date | undefined;
  profile?: any;
  services?: any;
}

interface MyProfile {
  image: string;
  name: string;
}

interface UserWrapper extends User{
  profile ?: Profile;
}
```

Comment: No, I can't. `Meteor.user()` return a `User` object. One will never instantiate a `User` object himself.

Comment: Or I can use your solution then make a new function that call `Meteor.user()` then return an object of `UserWrapper`